# Help understanding this admissions statement!

Tags: ratio, z-score

The statement reads:

"applicants invited to interview will be based on the z scores
of their MCAT total score percentile and their GPA combined in a 2:3 ratio."

From what I understand is that GPA is weighted more in this situation but a low GPA (lowest accepted this year was 78.5% and highest accepted was 96.5%, with a median MCAT 508 or 77th percentile). I currently have a 78.33% GPA and it seems that I can  offset the low GPA with a high MCAT. But I don't know to what extent I have to score.

Comment: For those of us not in the US, could you explain what these scores are and what they mean?

Comment: The MCAT is an admission test that is scored from 472 (lowest score) to 528 (highest score). The scores are standardized and given to you in a percentile. A total score of 508 is a 77th percentile.

Answer (score 1):

This admissions boundary seems to be well defined, but... it may not be fixed.

- The computation of z-scores may depend from year to year. I imagine they use some standardization table for the specific year when the MCAT and GPA have been done, and the table for MCAT does not exist yet. (or, I don't know, are the scores standardized according to z-scores, like with IQ tests)
- The required minimal z-score may depend from year to year. I imagine they may possibly select a top-x of candidates, and then the required z-score depends on the admissions of other people.

Do you know whether I am right about the above two points?

---

To obtain an idea of a required MCAT score you could look at the person that the 78.5% score on the GPA last year which corresponds to your current score. But you should note that this is a very rough estimate.

If you have more information you could look at more students and changes from year to year.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes the z-score varies For each category from year to year. Thus, the minimum MCAT score I need would also vary. I assume the better the competition the higher MCAT I will need. The closest interviewed stat I found was an individual with a 79% and a 513 MCAT score.